# Lizardfolk Ranger Spell Attribute for Innate Cantrip

Tags: magic, pathfinder-2e, races, cantrips

A [Lizardfolk](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=15) [Ranger](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=9) with the Ancestry Feat [Bone Magic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2401). He has +2 Wisdom and +0 Charisma modifier.
He chooses [Puff of Poison](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=977) as his innate cantrip granted by Bone Magic. Bone Magic does not mention any specific modifier to be used as Spell DC, so the [innate spells rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=279) apply and charisma mod is used - resulting in a spell dc of 13 and 0 initial damage.

The Ranger class details say

> Your warden spells are primal spells. When you first gain a warden
> spell, you become trained in primal spell attacks and spell DCs. Your
> spellcasting ability is Wisdom

I conclude that if said ranger does not have a warden spell, his innate cantrip would work as stated above. But if he would chose a feat that gives him a warden spell like [Gravity Weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1763) at level 1 *or later on* his spell attack and spell DC would change.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Innate Spells use Charisma

> You're always trained in spell attack rolls and spell DCs for your
> innate spells, even if you aren't otherwise trained in spell attack
> rolls or spell DCs. If your proficiency in spell attack rolls or spell
> DCs is expert or better, apply that proficiency to your innate spells,
> too. You use your Charisma modifier as your spellcasting ability
> modifier for innate spells unless otherwise specified.

As you've pointed out, the innate spell rules would have the Charisma mod used because there is no otherwise specified ability. Having warden spells doesn't change that, though it may increase the innate spell DCs and spell attack rolls if the character becomes expert or better with the warden spells.

Comment: So, the Ranger would have a Primal Spell DC of 13 for the primal innate cantrip Poison Puff and a Primal Spell DC of 17 (assuming WIS +4) for his focus spells which are primal spells.

This seems... *wrong* because a character shouldn't have two seperate Spell DCs for the same magical tradition.

Comment: They're the same tradition but from *very* different sources. Your proficiency indicates your skill with which you wield Primal magic... your ability score indicates how well you draw from the source.